# remove new lines inside the column content in csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, teradata-sql-assistant

I have the following sample csv file:

```
'TEXT';'DATE'
'hello';'20/02/2002'
'hello!
how are you?';'21/02/2002'
```

So, as you can see, the separator between columns is `;` and the content of each column is delimited by `'`. This brings me problems when processing the file with pandas, because it uses line breaks as a delimiter between rows. That is, it interprets the line break between "hello!" and "how are you" as a separator between rows.

So what I would need is to remove the newlines within the content of each column, so that the file looks like this:

```
'TEXT';'DATE'
'hello';'20/02/2002'
'hello! how are you?';'21/02/2002'
```

Removing the `r'\n` sequence would not work, because then I would lose the row separation.
What can I try? I'm using Teradata SQL Assistant to generate the csv file.

Comment: Teradata SQL Assistant also has an option (Tools / Options / Export) specifically to "Replace Carriage Returns in column data with blanks"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sep=` and `quotechar=` parameters in `pd.read_csv`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep=';', quotechar="'")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                     TEXT        DATE
0                   hello  20/02/2002
1  hello!\r\nhow are you?  21/02/2002
```

If you want to further replace the newlines:

```py
df['TEXT'] = df['TEXT'].str.replace('\r', '').str.replace('\n', ' ')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                  TEXT        DATE
0                hello  20/02/2002
1  hello! how are you?  21/02/2002
```